# cy.visit() failed because while attempting to visit a second unique domain/location/url in a single test case

Tags: cypress

I need to navigate two different urls in a single Test but when am navigating second one , it giving me error
1.FirstUrl- "https://app.ca-test.com/Public/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"
2.SecondUrl -"https://www.mailinator.com/"(location and origin is change)

"cy.visit() failed because you are attempting to visit a URL that is of a different origin."

I used cy.request() also but didn't work
so how can we do this??
But i have to navigate two urls in single test, and can not divide test case. This is my TestCase

Answer (score 2):

Cypress is preventing going cross origin since always forever. This was kinda covered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495996/cypress-e2e-testing-how-to-get-around-cross-origin-errors), but only kinda.

To sum up:

- Different domains in one test are not officially supported, at least not yet. There is a whole section regarding this in the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites)
- There is a [feature request on their board](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944) to support more than
  one, but I don't see it being implemented anytime soon, there are some workarounds posted in that ticket, maybe one of them will work for you.
- You could disable chrome [cross-origin security](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Disabling-Web-Security) by adding `chromeWebSecurity: false` to the `cypress.json` config file
- If you want to use Mailinator to check/send emails, why do you have to visit the site? Just use [their API](https://manybrain.github.io/m8rdocs/#message-api) and [cy.request()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax)
- Never link your test environment directly here.