# Why my localhost does not work in Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress, backend, e2e

I have a problem with Cypress. I have localhost fired up and in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) my app opens. On the other hand, in Cypress when enabling tests (Chrome, Firefox, Electron), I have a problem with the backend. The login page opens, but when I enter my login details, I get an error related to the backend.

Cypress version 12.14.0

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdFU2.png)

[Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uegRA.png)

I tried doing downgrades to lower versions of Cypress, I uninstalled and installed NPM on the frontend and backend.

In Firefox, it shows an error like this "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: same-origin rules prevent reading of remote resource (Reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null)". In Chrome, it only shows such an error "TypeError: NetworkError when trying to retrieve a resource.". But as I say, in a "normal" browser everything works ok. Only when firing up the tests there is an error.

chromeWebSecurity is set to false of course.

Things I have already tried:

- Tested to see if using a Incognito instance was the issue.
- Removed frontend project, removed Cypress folders including cache folder and pulled project down again.
- Tested if it was only relating to Chromium browsers. Issue exists in Firefox also.
- Set flags in the cypress.json folder for chromeWebSecurity to false.
- Tried different login methods using the UI and also using cy.session
- Tried pausing the Test Runner, manually opened a new tab, enter localhost, tried to log in, the same error
- A colleague also tried to fire it up on another laptop
  In the end, I did a laptop format (Macbook Air 2015) because it needed a refresh anyway

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message you are facing

Comment: In Firefox, it shows an error like this "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: same-origin rules prevent reading of remote resource (Reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null)". In Chrome, it only shows such an error "TypeError: NetworkError when trying to retrieve a resource.". But as I say, in a "normal" browser everything works ok. Only when firing up the tests there is an error.

Comment: did you try to set setting { "chromeWebSecurity": false } in your  'cypress.json' ? this link might be helpful how to avoid CORS errors-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495996/cypress-e2e-testing-how-to-get-around-cross-origin-errors

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: chromeWebSecurity is set to false of course. I updated my post.

Comment: I just updated things I have already tried